# Prove that the equality holds (complex numbers)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Please, could anyone help me to prove that this equality holds? I compute some integrals, using residuals and I know the result, but I am not able to recompose my result to the one which is on the right side.

$$
i\pi \frac {1 - i - i \sqrt{2}}{8e^{\frac{1}{8}i\pi}} = \frac{\pi}{8 \sin \frac{\pi}{8}}
$$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have tried many ways, but I am not able to put away cos(pi/8) if I rewrite exp(1/8 ipi)

Comment: Write the numerator on the left as $\sqrt2[e^{\frac{-i\pi}4}+e^{\frac{-i\pi}2}]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$1-\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})=2\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{8})$$

$$1+\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})=2\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{8})$$

$$cos(\frac{\pi}{8})=(1+\sqrt{2})\sin(\frac{\pi}{8})$$

Comment: thank you, it helps me so much! I should recognize this by myself...

Answer (score 1):

Set $\pi/8=\alpha$ for convenience. What you want to see is that
$$
(1+\sqrt{2}+i)\sin\alpha=\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha
$$
that is,
$$
\cos\alpha=(1+\sqrt{2})\sin\alpha
$$
which is the same as
$$
\cos^2\alpha=(3+2\sqrt{2})\sin^2\alpha
$$
or
$$
\sin^2\alpha=\frac{1}{4+2\sqrt{2}}
$$
that becomes
$$
\frac{1-\cos2\alpha}{2}=\frac{1}{4+2\sqrt{2}}
$$
or
$$
\cos2\alpha=1-\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{2}}=
\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{2+\sqrt{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
which is true. Since all steps are reversible, you get your identity (the step where I squared both sides is reversible because both terms are positive).

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**  Ah, I see your issue has already been resolved, but I'll just be leaving this here since I already spent the time on it.

---

After working through this, I'm sure there's another way that's shorter, especially since the last few steps are extremely counterintuitive.  But here's one way.

\begin{align*}
  i \pi \frac{1-i-i\sqrt2}{8e^{i\pi/8}} &= \frac\pi8 ie^{-i\pi/8}[1 - i(1+\sqrt2)]\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac\pi8 i\left(\cos \frac\pi8 - i\sin\frac\pi8\right)[1 - i(1+\sqrt2)]\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac\pi8 i \left(\cos\frac\pi8 - i(1 + \sqrt2)\cos\frac\pi8 - i\sin\frac\pi8 + i^2 (1+\sqrt2)\sin\frac\pi8 \right)\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac\pi8 i \left(\cos\frac\pi8 - i(1 + \sqrt2)\cos\frac\pi8 - i\sin\frac\pi8 - (1+\sqrt2)\sin\frac\pi8 \right)\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac\pi8 \left(i\cos\frac\pi8 - i^2(1 + \sqrt2)\cos\frac\pi8 - i^2\sin\frac\pi8 - i(1+\sqrt2)\sin\frac\pi8 \right)\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac\pi8 \left(i\cos\frac\pi8 + (1 + \sqrt2)\cos\frac\pi8 + \sin\frac\pi8 - i(1+\sqrt2)\sin\frac\pi8 \right)\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac\pi8 \left((1+\sqrt2)\cos\frac\pi8 + \sin\frac\pi8 + i\left[\cos\frac\pi8 - (1+\sqrt2)\sin\frac\pi8\right]\right)
\end{align*}

**FUN FACT:**  $\displaystyle \cos\frac\pi8 = (1+\sqrt2)\sin\frac\pi8$

**PROOF OF FUN FACT:**
\begin{align*}
  \frac{\cos\frac\pi8}{\sin\frac\pi8} &= \cot\frac\pi8\\[0.3cm]
    &= \cot\left(\frac12 \cdot \frac\pi4\right)\\[0.3cm]
    &= \cot \frac\pi4 + \csc\frac\pi4\\[0.3cm]
    &= 1 + \sqrt2
\end{align*}
Therefore $\displaystyle \cos\frac\pi8 = (1 + \sqrt2)\sin\frac\pi8$.  Substitute this into the last line of our chain of equations above and we get
\begin{align*}
  i \pi \frac{1-i-i\sqrt2}{8e^{i\pi/8}} &= \cdots\\
    &= \frac\pi8 \left((1+\sqrt2)\cos\frac\pi8 + \sin\frac\pi8 + i\left[\cos\frac\pi8 - (1+\sqrt2)\sin\frac\pi8\right]\right)\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac\pi8 \left( (1+\sqrt2)(1+\sqrt2)\sin\frac\pi8 + \sin\frac\pi8 + i\left[(1+\sqrt2)\sin\frac\pi8 - (1+\sqrt2)\sin\frac\pi8)\right]\right)\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac\pi8 \left( (3+2\sqrt2)\sin\frac\pi8 + \sin\frac\pi8 + i \cdot 0\right)\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac\pi8 (4+2\sqrt2)\sin\frac\pi8\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac\pi4 (2+\sqrt2)\sin\frac\pi8
\end{align*}

If it were me I would've stopped here (at the latest) but since your question is how is your answer equivalent to $\dfrac\pi{8\sin\frac\pi8}$ then we'll continue:
\begin{align*}
  i \pi \frac{1-i-i\sqrt2}{8e^{i\pi/8}} &= \cdots\\
    &= \frac\pi4 (2+\sqrt2)\sin\frac\pi8 \cdot \color{red}{\frac{\sin\frac\pi8}{\sin\frac\pi8}}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac\pi4 (2+\sqrt2)\sin^2 \frac\pi8 \cdot \frac1{\sin\frac\pi8}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac\pi4 (2+\sqrt2)\left[\sin^2 \left(\frac12 \cdot \frac\pi4\right)\right] \cdot \frac1{\sin\frac\pi8}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac\pi4 (2+\sqrt2)\left[\frac{1-\cos\frac\pi4}2\right] \cdot \frac1{\sin\frac\pi8}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac\pi8 (2+\sqrt2)\left(1-\frac{\sqrt2}2\right) \cdot \frac1{\sin\frac\pi8}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac\pi8 \left(2 - \sqrt2 + \sqrt2 - \frac22\right) \cdot \frac1{\sin\frac\pi8}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac\pi{8\sin\frac\pi8}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

One approach uses the fact that $\sin(\theta)=\dfrac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2i}$. After some simple manipulations, we get to

$$(i+1+\sqrt{2})\left(\frac{e^{i\pi/8}-e^{-i\pi/8}}{2i}\right)=e^{i\pi/8}$$

$$(1+\sqrt{2}+i)e^{i\pi/8}+(1+\sqrt{2}+i)\frac{1}{e^{i\pi/8}}=2ie^{i\pi/8}$$

$$(1+\sqrt{2}+i)\frac{1}{e^{i\pi/8}}=(-1-\sqrt{2}+i)e^{i\pi/8}$$

$$1+\sqrt{2}+i=(-1-\sqrt{2}+i)e^{i\pi/4}$$

Now use that $e^{i\pi/4}=\cos(\tfrac{\pi}{4})+i\sin(\tfrac{\pi}{4})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i$.

Comment: I have tried it but I am not able to get rid of cosinus